# Jmeter array variable conversion to string variable to pass as parameter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

```
{
      "data": {
        "companyIds": [
          5956,
          54841
        ],
        "userEmail": "abc@xyz.com",
        "contactId": 183334,
        "types": [
          1974,
          1975,
          1931,
          1932
        ],
        "boards": [
          168,
          169,
          175,
          180
          ]
         },
      "succeeded": true,
      "errors": null,
      "message": "Configuration fetched successfully",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
```

> Above is json response of API.  I have extracted variable in Jmeter
> using JsonExtractor as below- (debug sampler result)
> boardIDs_1=[168,169,175,180]
> boardIDs_ALL=[168,169,175,180]
> boardIDs_matchNr=1
> I want to convert that variable in format like (168,169,175,180)
> as I need to pass it as parameter to next API like-
> Parameters.condition=board_id in (168,169,175,180) and closedFlag =
> false
> How it can be achieved in jmeter?
> Can someone help how array [168,169,175,180] can be converted to string variable (168,169,175,180)?

Answer (score 0):

Add JSR 223 Postprocessor to the request where you're getting this response, and add the below code into the 'Script' area. You will get the boards_INDIVIDUAL as "168,169,175,180".

```
def rv = new StringBuilder()

1.upto(vars.get('boards_matchNr') as int, {
    rv.append('"').append(vars.get('boards_' + it)).append('"')
    if (it as String != vars.get('boards_matchNr')) {
        rv.append(',')
    }
})

vars.put("boards_INDIVIDUAL", rv.toString())
```